# Problems with adding a `lazy` keyword to C#

Tags: c#, properties, keyword

I would love to write code like this:

```
class Zebra
{
    public lazy int StripeCount
    {
        get { return ExpensiveCountingMethodThatReallyOnlyNeedsToBeRunOnce(); }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Why? I think it looks better than:

```
class Zebra
{
    private Lazy<int> _StripeCount;

    public Zebra()
    {
        this._StripeCount = new Lazy(() => ExpensiveCountingMethodThatReallyOnlyNeedsToBeRunOnce());
    }

    public lazy int StripeCount
    {
        get { return this._StripeCount.Value; }
    }
}
```

The first time you call the property, it would run the code in the `get` block, and afterward would just return the value from it.

My questions:

1. What costs would be involved with adding this kind of keyword to the library?
2. What situations would this be problematic in?
3. Would you find this useful?

I'm not starting a crusade to get this into the next version of the library, but I am curious what kind of considerations a feature such as this should have to go through.

Comment: Language designers invariably prefer features to be added in libraries rather than through the language.

Comment: I'm considering how it would/should/could interact with auto properties.

Comment: @MartinhoFernandes: or any property with a setter for that matter

Comment: @David: Not necessarily. We tried for years to add data access features in libraries and got ADO, DAO, ADO.NET, ODBC, and a whole alphabet soup of other data access technologies, none of which present a consistent interface. That's what motivated LINQ; by putting sorting, searching, etc, in the language we provide a common interface to many different underlying data providers. Putting stuff in languages is awesome, but it is expensive and therefore we want to reserve that for only the most valuable features.

Comment: @Eric You clearly did prefer libraries in this example, for a long long time -  witness your list of soups. It was only after this brought home the insufficiency for data access that you added it to the language. For what it's worth I don't consider any of the above to have been a mistake. You should only add to the language when you are sure it is the right decision to do so.

Comment: Not worth an answer, but adding a keyword will break some existing code.  I have seen this argument mentioned in C++ potential feature discussions before, though I speculate that it might have a slightly lower cost in the minds of MS architects.  Eric's provides another keyword-is-special spin (usually reserved for highly impactful features), though I would say it is similar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should C# have a lazy key word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332189/should-c-sharp-have-a-lazy-key-word)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> I am curious what kind of considerations a feature such as this should have to go through.

First off, I write a blog about this subject, amongst others. See my old blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/

and my new blog:

http://ericlippert.com

for many articles on various aspects of language design.

Second, the C# design process is now open for view to the public, so you can see for yourself what the language design team considers when vetting new feature suggestions. See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/ for details.

> What costs would be involved with adding this kind of keyword to the library?

It depends on a lot of things. There are, of course, no cheap, easy features. There are only less expensive, less difficult features. In general, the costs are those involving designing, specifying, implementing, testing, documenting and maintaining the feature. There are more exotic costs as well, like the opportunity cost of not doing a better feature, or the cost of choosing a feature that interacts poorly with future features we might want to add.

In this case the feature would probably be simply making the "lazy" keyword a syntactic sugar for using `Lazy<T>`.  That's a pretty straightforward feature, not requiring a lot of fancy syntactic or semantic analysis.

> What situations would this be problematic in?

I can think of a number of factors that would cause me to push back on the feature.

First off, it is not necessary; it's merely a convenient sugar. It doesn't really add new power to the language. The benefits don't seem to be worth the costs.

Second, and more importantly, it enshrines a *particular* kind of laziness into the language. There is more than one kind of laziness, and we might choose wrong.

How is there more than one kind of laziness? Well, think about how it would be implemented. Properties are already "lazy" in that their values are not calculated until the property is called, but you want more than that; you want a property that is called once, and then the value is cached for the next time. By "lazy" essentially you mean a memoized property. What guarantees do we need to put in place?  There are many possibilities:

Possibility #1: Not threadsafe at all. If you call the property for the "first" time on two different threads, anything can happen. If you want to avoid race conditions, you have to add synchronization yourself.

Possibility #2: Threadsafe, such that two calls to the property on two different threads both call the initialization function, and then race to see who fills in the actual value in the cache. Presumably the function will return the same value on both threads, so the extra cost here is merely in the wasted extra call. But the cache is threadsafe, and doesn't block any thread. (Because the threadsafe cache can be written with low-lock or no-lock code.)

Code to implement thread safety comes at a cost, even if it is low-lock code. Is that cost acceptable? Most people write what are effectively single-threaded programs; does it seem right to add the overhead of thread safety to every single lazy property call whether it's needed or not?

Possibility #3: Threadsafe such that there is a strong guarantee that the initialization function will only be called once; there is no race on the cache. The user might have an implicit expectation that the initialization function is only called once; it might be very expensive and two calls on two different threads might be unacceptable. Implementing this kind of laziness requires full-on synchronization where it is possible that one thread blocks indefinitely while the lazy method is running on another thread.  It also means there could be deadlocks if there's a lock-ordering problem with the lazy method.

That adds even more cost to the feature, a cost that is borne equally by people who do *not* take advantage of it (because they are writing single-threaded programs).

So how do we deal with this?  We could add three features: "lazy not threadsafe", "lazy threadsafe with races" and "lazy threadsafe with blocking and maybe deadlocks". And now the feature just got a whole lot more expensive and *way* harder to document. This produces an *enormous* user education problem. Every time you give a developer a choice like this, you present them with an opportunity to write terrible bugs.

Third, the feature seems weak as stated. Why should laziness be applied merely to properties?  It seems like this could be applied generally through the type system:

```
lazy int x = M(); // doesn't call M()
lazy int y = x + x; // doesn't add x + x
int z = y * y; // now M() is called once and cached.
               // x + x is computed and cached
               // y * y is computed
```

We try to not do small, weak features if there is a more general feature that is a natural extension of it. But now we're talking about really serious design and implementation costs.

> Would you find this useful?

Personally? Not really useful. I write lots of simple low-lock lazy code mostly using Interlocked.Exchange. (I don't care if the lazy method gets run twice and one of the results discarded; my lazy methods are never that expensive.) The pattern is straightforward, I know it to be safe, there are never extra objects allocated for the delegate or the locks, and if I have something a little more complex I can always use `Lazy<T>` to do the work for me. It would be a small convenience.

Comment: Just wondering, wouldn't a kind of compiler extensibility feature (which can also extend syntax, like in Nemerle) allow users to add the exact sugar that they need, without having to ask the language designers? Is this kind of metaprogramming on the pipeline for C# 5? I guess this kind of question would just not be asked anymore...

Comment: @Jordão: to answer your first question: yes. To answer your second question: no. The major feature for the next version of C# will be asynchrony.  To expand on the first question a bit: we all think that metaprogramming is in general awesome and want to make C# more able to do metaprogramming. However, that does not necessarily imply that it is a good idea to allow users to define radically new syntaxes. That could cause the language to fragment into a bunch of mutually illegible dialects, and we wish to avoid that outcome.

Comment: @Eric: I completely agree. When I first saw C# 1.0 and I saw those weird annotations that you put into elements (attributes) I thought I could use them to change the generated code. It was very disappointing to learn they were "just" opaque metadata to the compiler. But anyway, I think they're the first line-of-attack to add these capabilities: attributes that the compiler calls back during compilation. Like what [CciSharp](http://ccisamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CciSharp) does.

Comment: ... It solves the [exact problem](http://ccisamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LazyProperty&referringTitle=CciSharp) that the OP asked.

Comment: Also, you'd benefit from this in your own projects, like with Code Contracts.

Comment: @Jordão: Hah, I was just typing up a comment saying exactly that: Code Contracts is the sort of feature that can really work well in a language with "smart" compilation-time attribute processing. As we continue working on the "compiler as a service" design, we'll keep thinking about these sorts of compile-time scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

The system library already has a class that does what you want: [`System.Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx)

I'm sure it could be integrated into the language, but as [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) will tell you adding features to a language is not something to take lightly. Many things have to be considered, and the benefit/cost ratio needs to be very good. Since [`System.Lazy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) already handles this pretty well, I doubt we will see this anytime soon.

Comment: How do you calculate the benefit/cost ratio of adding a keyword?  Like the async/await keywords?  Why did those get the special treatment of keywords instead of just returning the appropriate classes?

Comment: @NickLarsen: with await/async, the implementation of the state machine behind the scenes is where there is serious value added.

Comment: @NickLarsen: Because the transformation that "await" induces on the program is *enormous*. It completely rewrites the method into continuation passing style. It's a hugely expensive feature, but it has big benefits. The keyword approach turns complicated, "inside out" code into straightforward linear code, and puts the burden of rewriting it into the crazy form on the compiler. That's of real benefit to customers.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know about the [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) class that was added in .Net 4.0?

http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/10/04/laziness-in-c-4-0-lazyt/

Answer (score 3):

This is unlikely to be added to the C# language because you can easily do it yourself, even without `Lazy<T>`.

A simple, *but not thread-safe*, example:

```
class Zebra
{
    private int? stripeCount;

    public int StripeCount
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.stripeCount == null)
            {
                this.stripeCount = ExpensiveCountingMethodThatReallyOnlyNeedsToBeRunOnce();
            }
            return this.stripeCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could easily do simple properties yourself, yet auto properties were added to the language. Which goes to show that how easy it is to implement it yourself is not really the crux of the matter. It's more the cost-benefit ratio (like it seems to always be).

Comment: Automatically implemented properties are beneficial to most if not all C#/VB projects, but adding a language construct to handle a case that already has a simple workaround both manually and through libraries and adds relatively little expressive power to the language is unlikely to be highly prioritized.

Comment: Note that you are making the assumption here that this is only accessed from one thread. There are race conditions if this code is accessed from multiple threads.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tryed / Dou you mean this?

```
private Lazy<int> MyExpensiveCountingValue = new Lazy<int>(new Func<int>(()=> ExpensiveCountingMethodThatReallyOnlyNeedsToBeRunOnce()));
        public int StripeCount
        {
            get
            {
                return MyExpensiveCountingValue.Value;
            }
        }
```

#### EDIT:

after your post edit I would add that your idea is definitely more elegant, but still has the same functionallity!!!.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using a post-compiler, [CciSharp](http://ccisamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CciSharp) has [this feature](http://ccisamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LazyProperty&referringTitle=CciSharp):

```
class Zebra {
  [Lazy] public int StripeCount {
    get { return ExpensiveCountingMethodThatReallyOnlyNeedsToBeRunOnce(); }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `Lazy<T>` type. Also ask Eric Lippert about adding things like this to the language, he would no doubt have a view.