# Is there a gcc extension for c++ short-circuiting?

Tags: c++, gcc, short-circuiting

I'd like to overload `operator&&` and `operator||` on a custom class, and I'd like for the overloaded operators to obey the short-circuiting behavior of their native counterparts.

I know that there is no mechanism for this in the c++ language, but I'm wondering if perhaps gcc might have some sort of extension that would make this possible. I know that such an extension would cause gcc to violate the official c++ standard, but I see a disclaimer on the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) that reads, "*By default, GCC also provides some additional extensions to the C++ language that on rare occasions conflict with the C++ standard*", so it doesn't seem outlandish to ask.

If there is a fundamental reason why such a extension simply could not work, even in theory, that would also be good to know for educational purposes. It feels to me like a `short_circuit_inline` keyword that can be used as a drop-in replacement for `inline` would have a well-defined meaning and straightforward implementation, but maybe I am wrong.

For what it's worth, I currently have a macro workaround, `AND(x,y,...,z)` that does a short-circuited `x && y && ... && z` for instances of my custom class. My desire for the operators is somewhat just for cosmetic purposes.

Comment: How would the operators work? They couldn't take two arguments, since you don't know if the second one should be evaluated or not. As an alternative, why not just provide an explicit conversion to `bool` and use the normal operators?

Comment: Are [expression templates](http://cpptruths.blogspot.de/2014/09/short-circuiting-overloaded-and-using.html) an option for you?

Comment: @AlanStokes I'd imagine that you define the operator with 2 arguments, decorated with my hypothetical short_circuit_inline keyword. The compiler can then inline-replace all calls of that operator with an if-else piece of code, with a variable corresponding to the second parameter only declared in the else-branch.

Comment: Also, for the suggestions to convert to bool and to use expression templates - they're not ideal for my context, but it will take some effort to explain why.

Comment: What does your macro actually do?

Comment: My macro `AND(x,y)` returns a `binary_expr<_AND,X,Y>`, which includes 2 members of type X and Y, where X=decltype(x) and Y=decltype(y). The constructor of this object copy-constructs x into the X member, and if necessary, y into the Y member. Failure to short-circuit can lead to runtime errors like division-by-zero.

Comment: Why can't you write an `operator &&` that does the same thing?

Comment: My evaluation is not lazy (there is a third field in my `binary_expr` object which stores the primitive value corresponding to the native evaluation, and that field is initialized in the constructor). So if I do `(x!=0 && (1/x))`, then without short-circuiting, I'll end up trying to construct the `binary_expr<_DIV,int,X>` represented by the `1/x`, which will be a division by zero. My macro on the other hand branches based on the value of `x!=0` and chooses to call a constructor that does not initialize the Y member.

Comment: @AlanStokes Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25913872/543913) of someone who came up with essentially the same macro solution I did.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "no". All gcc C++ extensions are documented here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html. There are no extensions listed there that work in the manner you've described.