# Short-circuit evaluation on C++ logical && and || operators

Tags: c++, c++11, operators, short-circuiting

User overloaded logical operators in C++ ( `&&, ||`) behave like regular functions. That is, both arguments in `bool operator&&(const T &a, const T2 &b);`are evaluated before entering the function, as entering a function is a sequence point[1] in C++. All good up to here.

Now, “builtin operators && and || perform short-circuit evaluation” [2][3], where there is a sequence point between the left and right sides. The cited reference isn’t clear what “builtin” are, only that they take `bool` operands, or convert them using “contextual conversion to bool”. It also mentions that only “two standard library classes overload these operators [because] the short-circuiting properties (...) do not apply to overloads, and because types with boolean semantics are uncommon.” [2]

Types with boolean semantics? How exactly do “builtin operators” work? Is it simply impossible to define logical operators with short-circuit evaluation?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

[2] http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: "Is it simply impossible to define logical operators with short-circuit evaluation?" Yes, it's "simply impossible". Your operator function needs both arguments, fully evaluated, which means the compiler simply can't do any short-circuiting. If you want short-circuit evaluation of a custom type of yours, then you need to implement conversion operators to `bool` instead of a logical operator.

Comment: My reading is that "builtin" refers to "this is a built-in language feature" as opposed to "this is part of the standard library". You can't make your own builtin operators, unless you make your own compiler with your own nonstandard extensions I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there actually a reason why overloaded && and || don't short circuit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913237/is-there-actually-a-reason-why-overloaded-and-dont-short-circuit)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think short-circuit can be implemented in user defined logical operations, that won't be trivial though

Answer (score 5):

You can imagine that a short-circuit `&&` acts like this:

```
bool b = expr1 && expr2;
```

first, it takes `expr1` and `expr2` and stores them in lambdas:

```
bool b = and_helper( [&]{return expr1;}, [&]{return expr2;} );
```

and forwards them to a helper, where `and_helper` is (simplified slightly):

```
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
bool and_helper( Lhs&& lhs, Rhs&& rhs ) {
  if (lhs()) return rhs();
  return false;
}
```

this has similar short-circuit behavior.

For user-overridden `&&` to work this way, we'd have to auto-lambda the arguments and pass said lambdas into the user-written `operator&&`.

So the only barrier for this to happen with user-defined operations is syntactic.  You can get the same behavior after a relatively mechanical transformation of your types, without resorting to magic.

The compiler just did a roughly equivalent operation (even before lambdas existed) when it ran into that construct.

Answer (score 0):

It means that short-circuiting doesn't apply to user-defined operators.

This is because, as you said, they behave like functions.