# about order of evaluation using shared pointers

Tags: c++, if-statement, shared-ptr, short-circuiting

I have a doubt about the order of evaluation in a if-clause when using shared pointers.

Suppose I have the following

```
struct MyClass {
   bool canUse(){ return false; } // dummmy value
}

std::shared_ptr<MyClass> myclass_ptr_;

/// other code..

if(myclass_ptr_ && myclass_ptr_->canUse()) {
   // do something
}
```

Do you know if in that case C++ always guarantees that `myclass_ptr_` is evaluated before `myclass_ptr_->canUse()`  ?

If it is not always the case and `myclass_ptr_` might come after for some reason and it is not initialised I am risking to surely crash the app.

When I run this app it seems working fine, but I just want to confirm with someone to avoid nasty surprises in a release.

Comment: The Left operand of `&&` is always evaluated first. if `false`, the Right operand is not evaluated. Unless if you are using a user-defined overload of `&&`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you know if in that case C++ always guarantees that `myclass_ptr_` is
>   evaluated before `myclass_ptr_->canUse()`  ?

Yes. This case doesn't fall under [order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) but [short circuiting](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) rule for `&&`.

From foot note on [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical).

> <sup>Builtin operators && and || perform short-circuit evaluation (do
>   not evaluate the second operand if the result is known after
>   evaluating the first), but overloaded operators behave like regular
>   function calls and always evaluate both operands</sup>

Also read [Why there is no circuiting when these operators are overloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913237/is-there-actually-a-reason-why-overloaded-and-dont-short-circuit).

Comment: @Jain: thanks a lot. The second comment is the one that probably clarifiy another doubt I had in mind.

Comment: I am glad if this helped :)